# SSH - Periodically require password even when public key is present

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

How do I allow public key authentication but still require user's password every 24 hours? Preferred host OS is Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the man page of [`sshd_config(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) I found a few configuration keywords that could be used to achieve this in some way:

1. Use modified [`AuthenticationMethods`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods) with a [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) block
2. Use [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand) to invoke a script on each login which decides whether a password is required
3. Use [`ForceCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand) to execute a custom command to check for a required password after successful login.

In Detail:

1. Use modified [`AuthenticationMethods`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods) with a [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) block: with this you can disallow public key authentication or *additionally* require password authentication for specific users:

```
Match User john
        AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

With this the user `john` is required to enter the password after successful public key authentication. But periodically changing *which* users should have to enter their password is a bit tricky. One way would be a custom script to change `sshd_config` to add/remove users and signaling `sshd` to reload its config - which is quite a nasty hack.

The only way I see to `Match` dynamically is by `Group`:

```
Match Group need-passwd
        AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

With this you don't need to change the `sshd_config` but only add/remove the users to the `need-passwd` system group respectively. `sshd` will then check whether the user is in that group and if so additionally require a password.

2. Use [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand) to invoke a script on each login which decides whether a password is required

```
# ignore existing authorized_keys files by default
AuthorizedKeysFile /dev/null
# instead load allowed authorized_keys using external command
AuthorizedKeysCommand /path/to/external_script.sh
# root is required to be able to read users ~/.ssh/authorized_keys files
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

Instead of `sshd` looking directly into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` this will only use keys provided by the `external_script.sh` where you can implement your custom logic, e.g.
* lookup the last successful remote login of the user
* if it was more than 24 hours ago return no authorized keys, effectively disabling public key authentication
* if it was within the last 24 hours simply return the contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The latter is the reason the `external_script.sh` needs `root` access to read the files in the users' home folder.

The downside of this approach vs. 1. and 3. is that you have to actually lower your security by allowing password-only logins.

3. Use [`ForceCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand) to execute a custom command to check for a required password after successful login.

Instead of executing the command supplied to the `ssh` client by the user the `ForceCommand` will be executed after successful login (with public key). In that command you can implement your custom logic (see above) and require the login password first if needed or otherwise just execute the supplied command line.

The downside here is that it is quite hard to get it right:
* since the command is only executed *after* successful login the user will already be logged in into the system - which means requested port/X11/ssh-agent forwarding may already be active before the password gets entered
* correctly handling the supplied command line - if any - may require considerate escaping of all strings

Also since the password/login is queried by a custom script this will not be supported/handled by the `ssh` clients but requires a working `tty`.

You could combine approach 2. and 3. by instead of returning no authorized keys prefix the lines with options to `restrict` all access and only executed the forced custom `command`, see the [AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT).

Comment: Very neat. I am going to use AuthenticationMethods with a Match block approach, cron to add all users to need-passwd group every night and pam_exec to remove users from the group on a sucessful login.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem. I had 2 other ideas before I landed on this one.

My approach would be to have a root cron job which runs at 3am and renames the users `authorized_keys` file to `authorized_keys.disabled`. This will make the user's ssh key fail and force a password login. Then, in the user's `.bashrc`, a line can simply rename `authorized_keys.disabled` back to `authorized_keys` so that logins for the rest of the day can use an ssh key.

The cron entry would be something like this:

```
00 03 * * * mv --force /home/jennifer/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/jennifer/.ssh/authorized_keys.disabled
```

And the `.bashrc` entry would be something like:

```
mv --force ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.disabled ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

There could be holes in my plan. I haven't tested it.

Comment: The huge drawback I see in this is that it fiddles around with files in the users' home which should be under the users' control. So a user could easily create their own cronjob/script to move the file back. Also it depends on the users `.bashrc` to work as intended by the admin.

Comment: I hadn't considered a user cron job to get around the password requirement, but that can be disabled with `/etc/cron.deny` (see `man crontab`). But you are right - this method can be bypassed by a very determined user. Then again, they're not bypassing security because they still must have a legitimate ssh key. Let the OP decide which method works best for him or her.

Comment: This plan could work with a trusted user group but it would indeed require some proofing for other enviroments. I will however use `cron` for the same purpose but with the method proposed by @acran